# How do I automatically do an SQL insert when creating a new node?

Tags: nodes, database

When creating a new node of a certain type, I want an SQL insert to be made at the same time.
The insert operation needs to use the node ID from the node just created, such as `INSERT INTO my_own_db (nid) VALUES ('last inserted node id')`.

Answer (score 5):

You've to create your [own module](http://drupal.org/node/361112) and after use a [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) you'll receive a $node object with all informations you need.